# How does one statically link the standard c++ runtime library in xcode 8

Tags: c++, ios, xcode8, static-linking, std

Using Xcode 8 how do I specify that I want to link statically with the C++ runtime libaries instead of dynamically (which is supposedly now the default on iOS)?

Comment: Nobody else has needed to do this?